# Passing Stripe Payment Methods to Laravel View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am trying to load previously used cards using the Stripe API using Laravel using this link from Stripe https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list?lang=php

Here is the snippet of code from my controller:

```
 $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
            'sk_test_51GueZuLq4MEy
          );


    $customer_id = "cus_HhnBT9fpjxW3hn";
    
    $paymentMethods = $stripe->paymentMethods->all([
            'customer' => $customer_id,
            'type' => 'card',
          ]);
    
    $pm = ($paymentMethods->data);
    
    return view('payment.details', $pm);
```

However when I am trying to pass the card data into my view I am unable to do so. The variable I am passing in views is:

```
{{ $pm }}
```

The error message I get is that my variable is not recognised. The data I am trying to access is `$paymentmethods->-data->card->last4`

Any help is always appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$stripe->paymentMethods->all` returns an object with a data attribute, where the data is an array of PaymentMethods, in this case, you'll likely want to access the first element of `data`.

Try updating to:

```
$pm = $paymentMethods->data[0];
```

Comment: I need to load all the payment methods. What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: In that case you could create a variable called $pms, assign `$pms = $paymentMethods->data` then iterate over $pms in the view.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm. Watched your Stripe video on save and reuse - excellent!